# Quick Action on related list

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, quickaction

In lightning you are not able to do URL hacking. In order to do any prepopulation of fields, it is suggested to use a quick action.

If we have a related list object and we are trying to prepopulate the object of the related list, we would make a quick action and remove the "New" button. However, to a user, this will probably be very confusing since sometimes the new button is on the related list, sometimes you have to go to the top right/highlights panel to find the quick action button. Is there anyway to standardize both quick action and "new" button?

The link below mentions that it is not possible to put the quick action onto the related list.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pDJlQAM

I thought about the idea of overriding the "New" button to call a quick action, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is alternate way not straight forward.

1. First you need to create a lighting action button in Parent Object(Account).
   [image]
2. Then you go to Child Object(Contact) create a new Listview button pass the url
   "/lightning/action/quick/Account.Show_Record_Id?recordId={!CASESAFEID(Account.Id)}".
   [image]
3. Account.Id is record id if you want to pass record id to flow or LWC.
4. Go to Parent Object(Account) and then in Page layout related list child tab add button.
   [image]
5. Below preview you view it quick action Preview.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the time of posting this answer. Please vote for this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TXFQA2).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_action_overrides.htm) you can override standard actions like the new button in the summer 17 release. I think the release is schedule for the coming weekend!

Another option for you could be to wrap your component in a VF page and override the button with that page.

Comment: Seems like a lot of development work for something as simple as prepopulating a couple fields. It went from extremely simple in classic to overly difficult.